# Why isn't the Fanatic badge awarded multiple times?

Tags: discussion, badges

Some badges can be awarded multiple times, and it seems logical that those badges do. But why not [Fanatic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/83/fanatic)? Surely 100 days of consecutive visits can be argued as a significant feat in itself? So what's  rationale for making it a one time only badge?

Comment: What would be your rationale for awarding it more than once?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I already explained why...

Comment: So if you visit for 200 consecutive days, you get 100 badges?

Comment: @MatthewLundberg No, for every 100 consecutive days you get 1 badge.

Comment: @0x499602D2, if you're referring to your next-to-last sentence, sure, 100 days are a significant feat. Once. We also want our members to have a life and to avoid completely burning out on SO, you know :)

Comment: I would have almost 13 fanatic badges.

Comment: To encourage us to go outside?

Comment: @StevenV - what is this outside of which you speak?

Comment: Yes, why? Where are my 17 fanatic badges? (in addition to the one I already have)

Comment: @MatthewLundberg That would be 101 badges, surely? 1st on day 100, 2nd on day 101, 3rd on day 102, ... 99th on day 198, 100th on day 199, 101st on day 200.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to venture a guess, that the badge is awarded when the counter for consecutive days in your profile (`visited X days, Y consecutive`) first exceeds 100.

That only happens once.

Comment: But you could say the same for the Yearling badge: "Active member for a year, earning at least 200 reputation. **This badge can be awarded multiple times.**"

Comment: Yeah, you get the badge when you cross your anniversary date, @Jongware. So how would you see Fanatic being awarded? Once every time you hit 100 days? Or once every additional 100 days (so first badge at 100, second at 200, third at 300...) And most importantly, **what behavior are you encouraging?**

Comment: @Shog9 What behavior is being encouraged by the badge in the first place? I almost think it's beside the argument to say it's not good behavior to award it multiple times (or maybe the badge simply isn't that great anyway).

Comment: It exists to encourage folks to visit the site regularly, @jdero. See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79995/get-rid-of-the-consecutive-days-requirement/80080#80080

Comment: @Shog9 Precisely - so why not encourage those who have visited frequently to continue to do so? I just think it's the same as most of the other multi-awarding gold badges.